# phonegap iOS rotation

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm working with the iOS simulator, it rotates fine, but unlike android the webview doesn't seem to re-size automatically.  The orientationchanged event fires but I'm not sure how to handle refreshing the page.  I can't do a whole page refresh, although it does solve the problem, since I'm using the multi-page JQmobile template.  Any thoughts on other ways to re-size?  I've tried $.mobile.trigger('pagecreate'); and pageshow.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0 target-densityDpi=device-dpi" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you kept this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no;" />
```

in `<head>` of the `index.html` in IOS it will automatically resize when device rotated.

Comment: I'll post mine, but it's pretty much the same.

Comment: I noticed I didn't have the cordova.ios.js file added, even after I changed it though it's not working.

Comment: I didn't have user-scalable=no that seems to have fixed it!  Thanks, though now I have a very strange thing where the values on my chart turn into links only when it's rotated to landscape lol, and only the numbers above the chart bars.

Comment: I take that back it was the height=device-height, I guess that's not needed.

Comment: Fixed the link thing, have to turn off phone number detection <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />